# Too many Garbage collection threads

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I am developing a software with java, it creates a thread upon receiving an event (from sensors). the time-to-live of these threads is very small (< 1 second)
The sensor sends <strike>maximal 10 events/minute.</strike>
This app works fine for most of the time. but sometime it hangs.
When looking at the eclipse debugger, I find out that there are to many threads and most of them are `"Thread[garbage collected]"` (about 800 threads @_@)

I don't know if that bug is caused by dynamic-creating-threads in my code or other bugs?

`EDIT:`
The problem is indeed caused by creating too many threads. I have logged all sensor's events with timestamp and there are some points it creates about `1200 events/minute` (damn!).
I also wrote a small java program which creates as many threads as posible. At `~4100th thread` (well, wooden computer) , jvm crashes. It does not hangs like my app does :-?. 
Therefore I suppose that there are (maybe) rare conditions while creating threads dynamically and it causes the garbage collection threads hang?

[image]

Comment: Why dropbox and not just plain image upload? 
At work we dont have access to dropbox

Comment: @Karna: Image upload for questions is only available with a certain reputation.

Comment: If you're running tests in Eclipse, it's possible that some threads survive the end of a failed test run, and so are left-over from prior test runs.  Are you being really careful to make all threads daemon threads besides the test runner thread?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't create a new thread for each event that is received. Instead, use the classes from the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Create an `ExecutorService` (using one of the static methods in class `Executors`) and submit jobs for handling events to the `ExecutorService`. The `ExecutorService` is a thread pool that manages the threads for you.

Comment: Threadpools are definitely the way forward here, they respond quicker and prevent native (off java heap) fragmentation caused by the large allocation required for the stacks.

Comment: Yes, thread pools are better for this task but why creation of many threads failing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I rewrote the code using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`. I'm gonna let it run for a day. hopefully it works out :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in NetBeans.  After a while, the program would hang with lots (maybe 500) of suspended threads.  However, when run *outside* the debugger it worked just fine.  I don't think I ever got more than a couple hundred threads going at once running when running outside, but the program did tend to start them at a furious rate.  My suspicion was that the debugger never shut down a thread and could only handle so many.

My experience so far is that the JVM handles vast numbers of rapidly starting and stopping threads very well, but that the NetBeans debugger (several versions ago now, one of the 6's) did not.