# Multithreading the work done within a for-loop by using a thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Suppose I have the following code which I wan't to optimize by spreading the workload over the multiple CPU cores of my PC:

```
double[] largeArray = getMyLargeArray();
double result = 0;
for (double d : largeArray)
    result += d;
System.out.println(result);
```

In this example I could distribute the work done within the for-loop over multiple threads and verify that the threads have all terminated before proceeding to printing the `result`. I therefore came up with something that looks like this:

```
final double[] largeArray = getMyLargeArray();
int nThreads = 5;
final double[] intermediateResults = new double[nThreads];

Thread[] threads = new Thread[nThreads];
final int nItemsPerThread = largeArray.length/nThreads;
for (int t = 0; t<nThreads; t++) {
    final int t2 = t;
    threads[t] = new Thread(){
        @Override public void run() {
            for (int d = t2*nItemsPerThread; d<(t2+1)*nItemsPerThread; d++)
                intermediateResults[t2] += largeArray[d];
        }
    };
}
for (Thread t : threads)
    t.start();
for (Thread t : threads)
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
double result = 0;
for (double d : intermediateResults)
    result += d;
System.out.println(result);
```

Assume that the length of the `largeArray` is dividable by `nThreads`. This solution works correctly.

However, I am encountering the problem that the above threading of for-loops occurs a lot in my program, which causes a lot of overhead due to the creation and garbage collection of threads. I am therefore looking at modifying my code by using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The threads giving the intermediate results would then be reused in the next execution (summation, in this example).

Since I store my intermediate results in an array of a size which has to be known beforehand, I was thinking of using a thread pool of fixed size. 
I am having trouble, however, with letting a thread know at which place in the array it should store its result. 
Should I define my own `ThreadFactory`?

Or am I better of using an array of `ExecutorService`s created by the method `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(ThreadFactory myNumberedThreadFactory)`?

Note that in my actual program it is very hard to replace the `double[] intermediateResults` with something of another type. I would prefer a solution which is confined to creating the right kind of thread pool.

Comment: How about using the `ForkJoin` framework? That framework allows you to cut up a big computational job into "fixed size" snippets, and distribute the resulting batch of snippets over a thread pool. Linky: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: Java 8 is being released next week and your use case is a perfect match for the new `Streams` API.

Comment: BTW let me assure you that "garbage collection of threads" is not at all your issue.

Comment: Also, a `ThreadFactory` won't help you because the main point of a thread pool is that it *doesn't* create new threads for each new task.

Comment: @user268396 `ForkJoin` does look promising, but I've been reading into `ExecutorService`s, so I will stick with that, this time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the reason why garbage collection came into this topic can be seen in [\[this post\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808648/too-many-garbage-collection-threads)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the reason I was thinking of using a `ThreadFactory` was that then I can supply a thread with information such that one thread will store its result in the same place in the array each time I do the computation.

Comment: That scheme wouldn't work because you are not in control of creating threads. A ThreadFactory creates a thread whenever, and only when, ordered to.

Comment: I actually got it working with a fixed thread pool (`Executors.newfixedThreadPool(int nThreads, ThreadFactory threadFactory)`) which may use a `ThreadFactory`. (The argument may be omitted.) Maybe you misunderstood what I meant by using a `ThreadFactory` - I meant using it in combination with an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having trouble, however, with letting a `thread` know at which place in the `array` it should store its result. Should I define my own `ThreadFactory`?

No need for that. The interfaces used by executors (`Runnable` and `Callable`) are run by threads, and you can pass whatever arguments to implementations you want to pass (for instance, an array, a begin index and an end index).

A `ThreadPoolExecutor` is indeed a good solution. Also look at `FutureTask` if you have runnables bearing results.

Comment: This straightforward answer is actually the right one. I was thinking the `Runnable` should know in which thread it is, which in turn knows to which place in the array it should store. That way I could say that thread 1 stores in place 1 of the array. Actually this thinking is just weird, since the threads are parallel and there is no intuitive way in which thread 1 is rightfully labeled '1'. I can just supply 5 (or in general: the number of cores I have) `Runnable`s each storing in a unique place in the array.

Comment: Would you agree that using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())` is a good thing to do?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by CPU bound. The reason I am using mutlithreading is to make running my code faster. Does that mean me task is CPU bound?

Comment: By "CPU bound" I mean "uses the CPU primarily to complete" instead of, say, I/O; in the I/O case, sizing a pool is far less obvious (depends on disk speed/connection speed/latency/etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

`ExecutorService` provides you with API to get the result from thread pool via `Future` interface:

```
 Future<Double> futureResult = executorService.submit(new Callable<Double>() {
     Double call() {
         double totalForChunk = 0.0;
         // do calculation here
         return totalForChunk;
     }
 });
```

Now all you need to do is to submit tasks (`Callable` instances) and wait for result to be available:

```
 List<Future<Double>> results = new ArrayList<Double>();
 for (int i = 0; i < nChunks; i++) {
     results.add(executorService.submit(callableTask));
 }
```

Or even simpler:

```
 List<Future<Double>> results = executorService.invokeAll(callableTaskList);
```

The rest is easy, iterate over `results` and collect total:

```
 double total = 0.0;
 for (Future<Double> result : results) {
     total += result.get(); // this will block until your task is completed by executor service
 }
```

Having that said, you do not care how much threads you have in executor service. You just submit tasks and collect results when they are available.

Comment: This is in fact a good solution to the example, but as I have (maybe unclearly) explicated, I cannot change the type of results to a list. The problem is more fundamental in my actual program: instead of one double result, the threads store their results in large data structures of doubles. It would be very unhandy for the ExecutorService to return all these data structures and place them at the right spots.

Comment: You can always pass target data structures to callable instances and put results directly there. It is not required to return anything from job. But you can still use Feature.get() to sync on job completion.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off creating "worker" threads that take information about work to be performed from a queue. Your process would then be to create an initially empty WorkQueue and then create and start the worker threads.  Each worker thread would pick up its work from the queue, do the work, and put the work on a "finished" queue for the master to pick up and handle.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a SingleThreadExecutor. (See the second to last paragraph of my post)